# Angularjs UI always show last infowindow

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using angularjs [UI-map](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map), I loop the data from firebase.
So far so good, but when I click on the markers and it always display the last query data.
here is snipper code

**In html**

```
    <!-- Setup Marker -->
    <div    ng-repeat="marker in markers"
            ui-map-marker="markers[$index]"
            ui-event="{'map-click': 'showMarkerInfo(marker)'}">
    </div>

    <!-- Setup Marker Info Window -->
    <div ui-map-info-window="infoWindow">
        <div>Marker - <input ng-model="full_name"></div>
        <div>Message</div>
    </div>
```

**In JS**

```
firebaseAuth.firebaseRef.child('/human/').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.users = snapshot.val();
    $scope.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.users.lat, $scope.users.lng);
    $scope.markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: $scope.latLng
    }));

});


        $scope.showMarkerInfo = function(marker) {
            $scope.currentMarkerLat = $scope.users.full_name;
            $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            console.log(marker);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried angular-ui, but this problem looks the same as the "[Javascript infamous Loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)", so you might want to try:

```
ui-event="{'map-click': 'showMarkerInfo(markers[$index])'}"
```

However, I guess it will suffer the same problem, but it's worth a try.